# How do I toggle an objects visibility in blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Its a pretty straight forward question.  I have tried using the visibility actuator but has no option for toggle.  I have also tried using an animation but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very easy to do. All you need is a Boolean property to be toggled, and when that property is true, the visibility will be true, and when that property is false the visibility will be false. In this case we are using **NameOfProp** as the name for the Boolean property, but of course it could be anything.

[image]

A working example can be found here.

[image]

Comment: Very useful solution! At first I didn't realize what was being controlled by "Visibility". Finally I realized it's the Physics Type: Occluder.